# How to prevent the removal of line breaks in a textarea in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I own a e-commerce store running on Wordpress + Woocommerce. Customers can customize their products by providing text through a text field. However, when they hit the purchase button, all the line breaks inside the text field get removed.

So if I input this:
**Line 1

Line 2

Line 3**

The result will be: **Line 1 Line 2 Line 3**.

This is a major problem and I have been trying to fix it without success. I found a few solutions, but I have close to no knowledge with PHP, so I could not bring any PHP solution like the nl2br() method to work. I have also tried CSS and jQuery, but that didn't work either.

I know where the PHP file that creates those text fields is located. Please see its content below. Is it possible to put something in there to prevent the line breaks removal from happening?

```
<?php foreach ( $addon['options'] as $key => $option ) :
$addon_key     = 'addon-' . sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] );
$option_key    = empty( $option['label'] ) ? $key : sanitize_title( $option['label'] );
$current_value = isset( $_POST[ $addon_key ] ) && isset( $_POST[ $addon_key ][ $option_key ] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST[ $addon_key ][ $option_key ] ) : '';
$price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price',
    $option['price'] > 0 ? '(' . wc_price( get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ) ) . ')' : '',
    $option,
    $key,
    'custom_textarea'
);
?>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-<?php echo sanitize_title( $addon['field-name'] ); ?>">
    <?php if ( ! empty( $option['label'] ) ) : ?>
        <label><?php echo wptexturize( $option['label'] ) . ' ' . $price; ?></label>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <textarea type="text" class="input-text addon addon-custom-textarea" data-raw-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $option['price'] ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ); ?>" name="<?php echo $addon_key ?>[<?php echo $option_key; ?>]" rows="4" cols="20" <?php if ( ! empty( $option['max'] ) ) echo 'maxlength="' . $option['max'] .'"'; ?>><?php echo esc_textarea( $current_value ); ?></textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `wc_clean()` you should use `wc_sanitize_textarea()`. This method sanitises the textarea input and preserves line breaks.

More information can be found at the WooCommerce [`wc_sanitize_textarea()` documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_sanitize_textarea.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This worked, yet it did not solve the problem. The line breaks are being kept when making the change that you suggested. However, a few steps further, the line breaks are removed again on the thank you page and on the invoice... I guess, I need to replace that wc_clean() method somewhere else, too.

Comment: @hanko Good to hear that this partially fixed your problem. If you want my help (or someone else's help) you'll have to add additional code to this question or create a new question with more information/code related to the thank you page and invoice. Since I don't know what your code does between the POST request and the output I cannot really help you, but you might want to take a look at [`nl2br()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) (according to your question you already have done this).